# React not sending value to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm new at react, and for training i'm doing a simple project to rank books. For now, the user types in the book he or she wants to vote for. If that input is empty, I return a error message, but if it's not it will return a sucess message.

Here's the input:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
     <input ref={input => this.input = input} /><br />
     <button type="submit">Tell us</button>
</form>
```

Here the onSubmit code binded to the input `onSubmit`

```
onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(this.input.value===''){
        console.log('========ENTRADA INVÁLIDA=========')
        this.setState({
            messageSucess: false,
            openDialog: true
        });
        this.input.focus();
    }        
    else{
        console.log('The user voted:')
        console.log(this.input.value)
        this.setState({
            bestBook: this.input.value,
            messageSucess: true,                                
            openDialog: true
        });
        this.input.value = '';
        this.input.focus();
    }
}
```

And the component I send the `messageSucess` variable will only check if it is true or false. If it is true, return the sucess message. If it's not, the error message. The code:

```
class DialogModal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        //Return's nothing if it's show property is false.
        if (!this.props.show) {
            return null;
        }

        //Return message of sucess or error.
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.messageSucess ? (
                     <div className="Modal">
                         <div className="Modal-Body sucess-message">
                             <br/>Thanks vor voting {this.props.children}, we will tell everybody about this sweet piece of violence.
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 ) : (
                     <div className="Modal">
                         <div className="Modal-Body error-message">
                             <br />Please, enter the book you want to vote for.
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

DialogModal.propTypes = {
    onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    show: PropTypes.bool,
    messageSucess: PropTypes.bool,
    children: PropTypes.node
};

export default DialogModal;
```

But for some reason the messageSucess is not getting to the DialogModal component. To be sure I tried to `console.log` it's value in several parts of the code, like before the return in the    `ModalDialog`, or just after 
   `this.input.focus()` in the main class, but it's always undefined. I've been following the [conditional rendering page of react](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) but got nothing so far.

**UPDATE: ** As asked in the comments, here's where I add the DialogModal component:

```
            <DialogModal 
                show={this.state.openDialog}
                onClose={this.modalOpened}>
            </DialogModal>
```

The `onClose` event will just change the show property to it's inverse. And I checked to be importing everything properly.

Comment: Could you update your post including the part where you add the Dialog component ?

Comment: Where do you set the value of `this.props.show`?

Comment: Update, @Striped

Comment: Need more information, but you have a minor error `onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}` instead of `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}`

Comment: @Damien, it is the value of openDialog variable. I added some code to the question, you can check it out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the messageSucess property to your Dialog like

```
<DialogModal 
  show={this.state.openDialog}
  onClose={this.modalOpened}
  messageSucess={this.state.messageSucess}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Striped.

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding :)